# `pnpm install` Usage Error: This project is configured to use yarn

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, pnpm

I am trying to migrate from yarn to pnpm. I ran `pnpm install`. It instantly failed and printed to the console:

```
Usage Error: This project is configured to use yarn

$ pnpm ...
```

I tried removing (renaming actually) `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` but to no avail. How to solve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out that it's because of:

```json
// package.json
{
 // ...
 "packageManager": "yarn@..."
 // ...
}
```

removing (or changing it to `pnpm`) would solve the issue. Additionally, `yarn.lock` existence doesn't have do with issue.

Comment: Without a reference to yarn, I solved this issue by adding `"packageManager": "pnpm@7.1.7"` (latest version at time of writing). I suspect the error is because both pnpm and yarn were setup on my local by node's corepack

Comment: I was trying to do `pnpm create next-app` in a new folder and was getting the same error. Had to create a package.json file and add `"packageManager": "pnpm@7.6.0"` to get it to work.

Comment: To be specific, this needs to be added in `package.json`.

Answer (score 10):

To whom it may concern, this error also happens when you have a package.json in your home directory specifying yarn as the package manager. This occured when I ran `yarn set version ...` at some point in my home directory.

You can fix this by changing the package manager in your current folder

```json
{
  //...
  "packageManager": "pnpm@<x.x.x>"
  //...
}
```

replacing `<x.x.x>` with your pnpm version,

OR

removing the yarn config from your home directory to avoid future problems:

```bash
rm -f ~/package.json ~/.yarn*
```

Comment: This happened to me on Windows. Accidentally I ran `npm install` on my user folder (one step above Desktop), so I received this error when trying to install something on Desktop.